# strpos not returning data

Tags: php

Ok, so I have a custom method that returns data between a start delimiter and end delimiter. I created it to mainly return data within a HTML file.

The sample data I'm using is:

```
url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fdomain.com%252Fvideo%253Fms%253Did%25252Cexpire%25252C
```

And the method is:

```
private function getValue($startDelimiter, $endDelimiter, $haystack) 
{
    $val = '';
    if($pos = strpos($haystack , $startDelimiter))
    {   
        $pos += strlen($startDelimiter);
        while($haystack[$pos] !== $endDelimiter) {
            $val .= $haystack[$pos];
            $pos++;
        }
        return $val;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm using the method like this

```
$this->getValue("url%3D", "%2C", $source);
```

The error I'm getting is

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 5880 in
```

If I use url decode, and then use

```
$this->getValue("url=", ",", urldecode($source));
```

... it works fine.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no %2C in your string, so it just continually iterates till it reaches the end of the string then is trying to read more and failing because it is already at the end of the string.

You should add something like:

```
if ($pos>strlen($haystack)) {
    return false;
}
```

Into your loop.

Also $haystack[$pos] is only one character while $endDelimiter is more than one character so that will never match unless your $endDelimiter is only a single character.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be because you are using an `$endDelimiter` that is > 1 character long. Since this is more than 1 character and your checking in `$haystack[$pos] !== $endDelimiter` it won't ever find the `$endDelimiter` as you are checking 1 character at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
while($haystack[$pos] !== $endDelimiter) {
```

will check *one* character of `haystack` against the multi-character `endDelimiter` of `%2C`. In other words, it will never match.

The reason your second one works is because the `endDelimiter` is actually a single character.

You need to check the `N` characters starting at `pos` against `endDelimiter`, where `N` is the length of `endDelimiter`, something like:

```
while (substr ($haystack, $pos, strlen ($endDelimiter) !== $endDelimiter) {
```

---

Of course, it may be easier to just use the offset version of `strpos` to locate the end delimiter, rather than traversing the string in your own code (this is untested since my PHP environments are inaccessible to me at the moment, but will hopefully work as is - at a bare minimum, it should at least give you an idea of what to do):

```
private function getValue ($startDelimiter, $endDelimiter, $haystack) {
    $pos1 = strpos ($haystack , $startDelimiter);
    if ($pos1 === false) {
        return false;
    }
    $pos2 = strpos ($haystack , $endDelimiter, $pos1 + strlen ($startDelimiter));
    if ($pos2 === false) {
        return substr ($haystack, $pos1);
    }
    return substr ($haystack, $pos1, $pos2 - $pos1);
}
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense! Thank you. Totally missed that.